# Make the first instance of a model have unique fields in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a Flask + SQLAlchemy app, with a `User` model. I want to enforce this business logic: that the first `User` created in the app should be an admin (ie has the field `is_admin=True`), but all other users should by default not be admins.

The model looks something like this (simplified):

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(UnicodeText, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(UnicodeText, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=True)
    is_admin = Column(Boolean(), default=False)
```

And I want this test case to succeed:

```py
first = User(username="foo", email="foo@foo.com", password="foobarbaz123")
second = User(username="bar", email="bar@bar.com", password="foobarbaz123")

db.session.add_all([first, second])
db.session.commit()

assert first.is_admin
assert not second.is_admin
```

---

I have tried a few approaches:

- Put this business logic in the API route itself. This has the major downside that it's not integrated in the model layer, so it's easy to bypass, and you have to maintain this functionality in multiple places.
- Put this logic into the model constructor, e.g.

  ```py
  def __init__(self):
       user_count = db.session.query(User).count()
       if user_count == 0:
           self.is_admin = True
  ```

  This doesn't work, because we can't assume that we have access to the database session at all times. For example, when constructing test data, it will involve hitting the database when the data is in an unstable state.
- Put this logic into an [`after_insert`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.after_insert) event, e.g.

  ```py
  @event.listens_for(User, 'after_insert')
  def receive_after_insert(mapper, connection, target):
       user_count = db.session.query(User).count()
       if user_count == 0:
           target.is_admin = True
  ```

  However this doesn't pass the test case, because it seems to update the model asynchronously.

How can this business logic be implemented?

Comment: may I ask "why" are you trying to implement it this way? _Especially after you yourself found it there are so many downsides or impediments to doing it this way_.
And what should happen if that first user is deleted from the database? Shall another one be promoted to be admin? Which one?

Comment: I don't quite understand. I have some logic that I need to implement, but don't know how to implement it. I'm not trying to implement it in any particular way, the method is what I'm asking about.

Comment: Hi @Migwell. I do not think there is the "best" solution for your question, but would be very curious to learn how you decided to go about it and why. Thank you.

Comment: The only (more) bulletproof way i see this can be done is by having an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the database level which would set the `is_admin` to `TRUE` if this is the first (the only) record in the database.